# Display table view structure

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, css

I am trying to display a table made from `<ul>` tags. And need its content to display one after another. This is my code

**css**

```
.activity-list-header > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 15.666%;
    list-style: outside none none;
}

.activity-list-body > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 15.666%;
    list-style: outside none none;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <ul class="activity-list-header">
        <li>Activity</li>
        <li>Session</li>
        <li>Rate Type</li>
        <li>Rate</li>
        <li>Qty</li>
        <li>Select</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="activity-list-body activity-list-body-1">
        <li>Activity name</li>
        <li>Session name</li>
        <li>Rate Type name</li>
        <li>Rate name</li>              
        <one-rate activity="activity" selected-date="selectedDate" >            
            <li>Qty name</li>
            <li>Select name</li>
        </one-rate>
    </ul>
    <ul class="activity-list-body activity-list-body-1">
        <li>Activity name</li>
        <li>Session name</li>
        <li>Rate Type name</li>
        <li>Rate name</li>              
        <one-rate activity="activity" selected-date="selectedDate" >            
            <li>Qty name</li>
            <li>Select name</li>
        </one-rate>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

My problem is that i need to display all content in a row, but this does not happen as the last two `<li>` are wrapped inside `<one-rate>` used in AngularJS. I am aware it is wrong to wrap `<li>` other than the use of `<ul>`. I need to know away to resolve this without changing the given `html` structure.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6kogq6z/)

Comment: @Tally <one-rate> is displayed in the html as i cannot include the entire scripting.

Comment: @Tally could you share a fiddle on the same as mentioned?

Comment: @Shanka just realized your problem is only styling.. should read more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML code isn't valid: only `li` elements can be children of `ul`. No custom element can be.

That said, neither Fx nor Chrome seem to be bothered by that and there's still a solution to your styling problem: by changing the selector `.activity-list-body > li` to `.activity-list-body li` (not requesting li to be direct child of this class, only **descendant**), your layout becomes correct.
Edit2: if you've sublists, then it won't work out of the box; you'll need to override 1 to 4 declarations from this rule...
Edit: didn't test in Saf or IE8-11+

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6kogq6z/1/

Comment: @ Felipe yes your right about the invalid code and as mentioned by me too, the developers are reluctant to change structures. Removing selector seems to be a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a long solution, but then all you have to do is remove the > in the css on .activity-list-body > li to make it work.

Comment: I answered and then saw the same response. So @FelipeAls was here first.